# Pycharm Query with the text cursor

Tags: python, pycharm

Hi I use Pycharm 2020 for my Python projects. But I think I messed up my text cursor. The text cursor is coming as a black box. I figured when you press INSERT on you keyboard it switches to the normal(I). But after I did that, Instead of typing normally it is replacing the text in front of the cursor. I noticed this is only happening in the pycharm application.

Comment: did you install VIM?

Comment: What is that?How do you check if you did

Comment: Settings -> Plugins -> Installed see if VIM is intalled or not?

Comment: No. IDEAVIM is not installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Uncheck the "Use block caret"

[image]

Comment: Hi I did that and now the text started typing properly but now the text cursor is coming as a block ::((( even though i unchecked it

Comment: Press insert once

Comment: It started working Much appreciated thanks for your time

Comment: Give an upvote if it working for you so that others can understand to the comment